Logseq - How to define a custom home page when exporting graph to HTML?
In logseq - is there a way to select a user define Homepage when exporting a graph to HTML?
Note:  In my case when exporting Graph to HTML the default page is a list of all the pages.
In logseq - is there a way to select a user define Homepage when exporting a graph to HTML?
Note:  In my case when exporting Graph to HTML the default page is a list of all the pages.  I like use as default a page that has pre defined links in it.
Default Logseq Home Page - when exporting graph to HTML.

Add this to config.edn maybe help:
:default-home {:page "overview"
           :sidebar "Contents"  }

